# Permission denied using Pool from multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use [this PRNG test](https://github.com/jameshanlon/prng-testing) without success due to an *OSError* given by *Pool* from *multiprocessing* after being built.

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I read several posts here trying to solve this problem but no one works.

Thanks!

Comment: need to see your code to be able to help with anything.

Comment: I run the lines given in the README.md.

Comment: Is `run-tests.py` set to be an executable file? And are you in a directory where you can create new files?

Comment: Yes, `run-tests.py` and `summarise-results.py` are executable and the output of `ls -la` in my directory is `drwxrwxrwx`.